# итерация по элементам вложенных списков

Tags: python, функции, list

Есть список типа: `pd=[[{1,2,3},[5,7,3]],[{2,7,8},[9,8,4]]]`. Нужно брать первый элемент вложенного списка и проверять, есть ли этот элемент во множестве слева. Если есть, то поиск прерывается и элемент добавляют в новый список `lst=[]`. В данном примере результат должен получиться следующий:

```
lst=[3,8]
```

Т.е. 3 добавили из списка `pd[0][1]` и 8 добавили из `pd[1][1]`. Ожидаемая длина pd, т.е. `len(pd)` = 6-9 вложенных пар (множество, список) за одну итерацию цикла. Всего итераций >25 000 000

Мой код представлен ниже, но я ищу более оптимальное решение, возможно, через функцию map, lambda или list comprehension

```
for i in pd:
    for j in i[1]:
        if j in i[0]:
            lst.append(j)
            break
```

Comment: Почему `3, 8`, а не 8? Первый элемент списка это индекс 1 или 0? Если индекс 1, то будут проверяться значения 7 и 8

Comment: Или вы имели ввиду поиск элементов из списка в множестве и при первом совпадении добавлять элемент в список `lst` и дальше не искать?

Comment: первый элемент списка - это индекс 0.

Comment: Если такой элемент всегда есть, то можно так `[next(filter(lambda x: x in el[0], el[1])) for el in pd]`

Comment: "Или вы имели ввиду поиск элементов из списка в множестве и при первом совпадении добавлять элемент в список lst и дальше не искать?" - да, именно так.

Comment: GrAnd, да, элемент всегда есть. Спасибо, это то, что я искал.

Comment: @GrAnd Лучше сразу "распаковать" значения на две переменных в `for`, чем использовать обращение по индексам

Comment: Ok. Тогда так: `[next(filter(lambda x: x in st, lst)) for st,lst in pd]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление первого элемента списка, что присутствует в множестве:

```
pd = [[{1,2,3},[5,7,3]],[{2,7,8},[9,8,4]]]
lst = []
for sets, lists in pd:
    for x in lists:
        if x in sets:
            lst.append(x)
            break
print(lst)
# [3, 8]
```

Совмещение перебора и проверки:

```
lst = []
for sets, lists in pd:
    for x in filter(lambda x: x in sets, lists):
        lst.append(x)
        break
print(lst)
```

---

Функциональная магия (если уверены, что хоть один элемент списка есть в множестве):

```
lst = [
    next(filter(lambda x: x in sets, lists)) 
    for sets, lists in pd
]
```

Если не уверены (что-то избыточно получилось...):

```
lst = [
    next(filter(lambda x: x in sets, lists)) 
    for sets, lists in pd
    if any(filter(lambda x: x in sets, lists))
]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. lst = [
    next(filter(lambda x: x in sets, lists)) 
    for sets, lists in pd] - это то, что я искал. И то, что указал пользователь GrAnd в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: `[sets, lists]` - квадратные скобки тут не нужны )

Comment: @Александр, пожалуйста :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо :)